# Creating a Pivot table using dynamic variables from a View

Tags: sql, variables, dynamic, view, pivot

Looking for some help as the title states. When I hard code Scenario1 as 'ACT' the pivot table works as shown in **"Script1"**. **"Script2"** is my attempt at dynamically setting it up (which is not working of course). Any help is appreciated!

**SCRIPT1**

```
SELECT
      year,
       GRP_LEVEL,
       ACT

FROM  

(SELECT
       Scenario1,
       year,
       GRP_LEVEL,
       TotalAmount
FROM    
[dbo].[VW_exp_by_dept1]) b

PIVOT  
(SUM (TotalAmount) FOR Scenario1 IN (ACT)) piv 

GROUP BY 

      year,
       GRP_LEVEL,
      ACT

--ORDER BY GRP_LEVEL 
GO
```

---

**"SCRIPT2"**

```
DECLARE @ScenarioA AS varchar (50); 
SET @ScenarioA = 'ACT';
(
SELECT
      year,
       GRP_LEVEL,
       @ScenarioA

FROM  

(SELECT
       Scenario1,
       year,
       GRP_LEVEL,
       TotalAmount
FROM    
[dbo].[VW_exp_by_dept1]) b

PIVOT  
(SUM (TotalAmount) FOR Scenario1 IN (@ScenarioA)) piv )

GROUP BY 
      year,
       GRP_LEVEL,
      ScnearioA


--ORDER BY GRP_LEVEL 
GO
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

a possibility is to use dynamic SQL. You build a string which includes your SQL query and excute it. A example would be:

```
DECLARE @ScenarioA AS varchar (50);
DECLARE @DynamicQuery as varchar(MAX);

SET @ScenarioA = 'ACT';

SET @DynamicQuery = '
SELECT
      year,
       GRP_LEVEL,'
       + CAST(@ScenarioA as varchar) + '
FROM  
(SELECT
       Scenario1,
       year,
       GRP_LEVEL,
       TotalAmount
FROM    
[dbo].[VW_exp_by_dept1]) b
PIVOT  
(SUM (TotalAmount) FOR Scenario1 IN (' + CAST(@ScenarioA as varchar) + ')) piv 
GROUP BY 
      year,
       GRP_LEVEL, '
      + CAST(@ScenarioA as varchar) + '
--ORDER BY GRP_LEVEL'

EXEC(@DynamicQuery)
```